# How to make sortable table on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable, blogger, tabular

I have blog, and want to create sortable table. But I can't find a way to make it. I only can make a normal table. 
I tried many tutorial about how to make it on blog, but didn't work. Maybe that codes are for WP, not Blogger. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow :). Unfortunately, your question is very broad. Can you add more details, please? E. g. the table you want to sort and code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with the previous answer that Datatables works with Blogger.

It's relatively simple:

On Blogger, on the sidebar on the left you will find the "Theme" link and in the Themes window you will customize your theme by selecting "Edit HTML". Just before the end of the head (just before the thead tag) add the following

```
    <script language='javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script language='javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <link href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

(Maybe the link element should be elsewhere in the template?)

And here's the example table code in the Post editor (HTML View)

```
    <table id="myTable" class="display datatable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Distance (km)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Amsterdam</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Utrecht</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Eindhoven</td><td>100</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Rotterdam</td><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Den Haag</td><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('.datatable').DataTable();});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Jquery datatable` is a good choice for adding sortable tables to your website.  What you need to do is to install Datatable on your blog and go ahead to invoke the Javascript on your table.

https://datatables.net/

1. To include the Datatable Javascript & CSS via the CDN, 
   Login to blogger.com and visit the dashboard of your blog.
2. Now, click on Theme from the left sidebar
3. From template window, click on Edit HTML.
4. Insert the Datatable Javascript and CSS CDN into the head tag or at the bottom before the closing tag.

   `<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`
5. Insert the CSS CDN reference tag into the head tag of your template

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">`
6. Compose your blog post. Click on HTML at the top left to switch to HTML view. This will enable you edit the table and it's content in HTML mode.
7. Edit your table and give it a HTML id or a class e.g

   `<table class="display datatable" style="width:100%">`
8. At the bottom of your HTML view editor, add a script tag to invoke datatable on your table (or any table with the CSS class datatable.

   `<script type="text/javascript">`
   `$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.datatable').DataTable();
   } );`
   `</script>`
9. Your datatable enabled blog post is ready for publishing. Please see a link to sample below. I created this while writing this answer. https://ehimex.blogspot.com/2018/10/name-position-office-age-start-date.html

You can refer to https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html for more options or details on how to configure a datatable.

Happy Coding!